# Create a product tag, or are they all off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, product-support

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25764012/1698557) that mentioned [Tuleap](http://www.tuleap.org/) (an open source application lifecycle management suite), and not knowing what it was I was surprised there wasn't already a tag for it.  A [search for questions that mention Tuleap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tuleap) returns 62 questions, about a third of which are from one user.  Most of these questions seem to be general product support and in my opinion are off-topic for SO, but I don't know enough about the product to say for sure.

Does it make more sense to create a Tuleap tag for the questions, or close them as off-topic, or some combination of the two?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/792066

Comment: If there are a significant number of tuleap-specific on-topic questions, feel free to create the tag by attaching it to relevant questions. Also, down-/close-voting (and, only where really appropriate spam-flagging) those other questions would be appreciated. Just leave those where you have doubts alone.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the input, I went through them and did just that.