# When does a product become eligible to get its own tag + other related tag lifecycle questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now, this is a hypothetical question, but I'm asking it because I may soon be in a position where it would become a reality and I don't really feel like doing the wrong thing.

Consider this scenario:
One developer (company that has multiple locations) has created a library which is open-sourced. So far the library itself does not have many open-source contributors since not many people have heard of it (naturally), but the company would like to maintain full exposure for the library, including its SO presence, even if initially this presence is only used by company's personnell. Hopefully in a short while, this would become a product used by hundreds of people making this question irrelevant (for the library in question), but I'm asking specifically about the starting scenario.

In searching for answer to this, I found the following questions and their respective answers, but was not satisfied with my findings, so below I ask some more in hope to get a sense of general direction one could take for such a scenario.

- [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)
- [How to add a new tag on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103676/how-to-add-a-new-tag-on-stack-overflow)
- [Create a product tag, or are they all off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271100/create-a-product-tag-or-are-they-all-off-topic)
- [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) (was suggested in previous one, but I don't think it's relevant for my scenario)
- [I am a user of a MATLAB library that lacks wide documentation. Am I encouraged to create a tag on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294334/i-am-a-user-of-a-matlab-library-that-lacks-wide-documentation-am-i-encouraged-t) (most relevant, actually suggested by SO's "Similar Questions" list)

Questions:

- Can the company use SO for what would initially be essentially its own internal Q&A about the library?
- Can the tag be created right away even if initial question count is expected to be low?
- What happens further on when additional tags would have to be created to separate the library's submodules? Leave existing questions as they were or re-tag them?

So far I've only dabbled in questions on existing stuff, so please forgive me if I'm asking trash, but I would appreciate some clarification on how exactly tag lifecycle is managed here. Or better yet - how product lifecycle is managed. Put as an example: when did android gain its eligibility to be asked about and when for questions about it to be tagged android?